# TP-Link TL-MR3220 DD-WRT не могу подключить USB флешку

Tags: dd-wrt, usb

Имею роутер TP-Link TL-MR3220 с прошивкой DD-WRT v24-sp2 (03/25/13) stdХочу подключить флешку, но не выходит(смотрю файлисистем и не вижу ext3:**cat /proc/filesystems**

```
    nodev   sysfs    nodev   rootfs    nodev   bdev    nodev   proc    nodev   tmpfs    nodev   debugfs    nodev   sockfs    nodev   pipefs    nodev   anon_inodefs    nodev   devpts            squashfs    nodev   ramfs    nodev   mtd_inodefs    nodev   usbfs
```

Хотел установить данные модули, но в данной папке ничего нет /lib/modules/3.5.7/kernel/fs

Вопрос: как установить поддержку ext3 и подключить флешку?

```
    root@DD-WRT:~# dmesg|grep scsi<6>[   11.170000] scsi0 : usb-storage 1-1:1.0<5>[   12.210000] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     JetFlash TS1GJFV30        8.07 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2root@DD-WRT:~# dmesg|grep sda<5>[   12.290000] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 2007038 512-byte logical blocks: (1.02 GB/979 MiB)<5>[   12.310000] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off<7>[   12.310000] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00<3>[   12.320000] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page present<3>[   12.320000] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through<3>[   12.340000] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page present<3>[   12.340000] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through<6>[   12.360000]  sda: sda1 sda2<3>[   12.370000] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page present<3>[   12.370000] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through<5>[   12.380000] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Саму флешку видит, но что делать дальше?

Comment: вы уверены что ядро 3.5.7 ? вообще сделайте find в /lib/modules

Comment: так а что, если сделать mount  она у вас не смонтируется ?

Comment: пытаюсь монтировать mount /dev/sda1 /mnt, но ошибок не выдает и df не показывает новый раздел.Find modules пробовал этих модулей нет.

Comment: на форумах ddwrt уже спрашивали ? там какой-то бардак был с ext*

Comment: нет не спрашивал